# join in linq with entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i need help to understand linq join. i found out a few topics related with this issue but i didnt found one with a good explanation of steps.

i normal query, i do this.

```
var q = from c in context.tableA
        select c;
        List<tableA> tableAList = q.ToList();
```

in q.ToList() its get executed the query, right?

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx) found some examples but i want to be clear about this,

```
 using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
 {
 ObjectSet<SalesOrderHeader> orders = context.SalesOrderHeaders;
 ObjectSet<SalesOrderDetail> details = context.SalesOrderDetails;

var query =
    from order in orders
    join detail in details
    on order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID
    where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
    && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
    select new
    {
        SalesOrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
        SalesOrderDetailID = detail.SalesOrderDetailID,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        ProductID = detail.ProductID
    };

foreach (var order in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2:d}\t{3}",
        order.SalesOrderID,
        order.SalesOrderDetailID,
        order.OrderDate,
        order.ProductID);
}
}
```

so from this example i can see that query can have more than 1 objetc but what about this "select new" ? is it called for each record in the DB ?

what type is that object? anyone i want or is order because is the first table in the query?

in case of the object is the first table, what happens if i need to have data that is not defined in this type of, i mean new attr.

other question, when is the query executed?

also, is this method good for response speed or are better solutions?

thx in advance. If there is a thread with this answers plz point me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in q.ToList() its get executed the query, right?

yes

> what about this "select new" ? is it called for each record in the DB
>   ?

new is just a new anonymous object, the query is ran against your table normally.

> what type is that object? anyone i want or is order because is the
>   first table in the query?

it's anonymous, you could do `select new Order {` though, if you have an Order class defined.

> in case of the object is the first table, what happens if i need to
>   have data that is not defined in this type of, i mean new attr.

You would have to select it or add the attribute/property to your object/class.

> other question, when is the query executed?

In the foreach loop

> also, is this method good for response speed or are better solutions?

Yes, it's fine

Comment: what u told me is correct. Now i get an error on the example. with the ON statment its said that order and details are not right with equals but with the where statment they work correct. any clue?

Comment: error: The name "order" is not within the area on the left side of 'equals'. Change the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

Comment: if someone care, the thing was that order matters here. i was putting details on on the left of equals and have to go on right.

Answer (score 1):

`Select new` is creating an anonymous type, you can put whatever fields you wish from both tables into it.
You can do some reading about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

The query is executed whenever you use it's results, it can either happen when you iterate(foreach) over it, or whenever you call toList(), toArray() or whatever on it.

This method is rather good for response speed. 
As with any generated SQL, it probably can be optimized according to your use case, but unless you have a really huge amount of data, it is totally sufficient.
Otherwise, you'd have to write a Stored Procedure, and map it with Entity Framework